# android activity recreate/restart after charged in/plugged in - out

Tags: android, restart

i got this problem in some device, mostly china rom, problem is when plugged-in/out, the onDestroy called, then onCreate called -> activity restart, i tried to find anything of code that relate to this problem but not working.

Can anyone help me know the problem? Thanks

more update:

Here is the sample of one screen

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen.ChatScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" />
```

i tested then all screen restarted, not only one, only some specific android device. Samsung work normal

Comment: This is how activity lifecycle works: shorturl.at/aoER2 .
As you are saying onDestroy is called, then onCreate is called.
Can you log print each lifecycle method and check if you are getting current flow as per the link I shared.

Comment: Original URL: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity

Comment: Sounds to me like you are seeing a configuration change, which will kill the current `Activity` and start it again. Can you capture the logcat when this happens and post it in your question?

Comment: In any case, your app needs to be able to handle this condition. It can happen pretty much any time, for any reason.

Comment: i tried to read the doc about configurationChanges but can find anything related to charge event :  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element